# i-phone sending mail automatically

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How i send email from IPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524549/how-i-send-email-from-iphone)

I want to send a predefined mail through my i-phone app.I know we can use MFMailComposeViewController.but i dont want to open a separate MFMailComposeView.when user click the send button mail should send automatically.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately iOS does not allow sending emails without the user noticing.

What you can do instead is use a server that sends the email for you. Like so:

iPhone -> sends request to server that includes the recipient, body, subject of the email -> server will send the email for the user

Note that this means that the sender address is not the users one.

Comment: "Unfortunately"? If it allowed it, there'd be lots of spam apps out there, which would *NOT* be a good thing :)