# Send Email without using MFMailComposer

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send mail without MFMailComposeViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263412/send-mail-without-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller)
>   [iphone app send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494626/iphone-app-send-email)
>   [How i send email from IPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524549/how-i-send-email-from-iphone)

I want to give an option to send email from my app without using MFMailComposer.

some thing like give the user 3 UITextField and get the subject,body, email address from there.

it is possible?

Comment: This question is a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4524549/840973 - I submitted the wrong question when flagging however this question is the dupe I intended to flag as

Comment: Can you please check this link.. it will surely help you to fix up the problem. Thanks,
Jigar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263412/send-mail-without-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a server side script to send through.  You could also use a class to send direct thru smtp, but the security is not the best this way.